# Drawing an Image to a JPanel within a JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am designing a program that contains two JPanels within a JFrame, one is for holding an image, the other for holding GUI components(Searchfields etc). I am wondering how do I draw the Image to the first JPanel within the JFrame?

Here is a sample code from my constructor :

```
public UITester() {
    this.setTitle("Airplane");
    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    searchText = new JLabel("Enter Search Text Here");
    container.add(searchText);
    imagepanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    imagepanel.paintComponents(null);
   //other constructor code
```

}

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawImage(img[0], -50, 100, null);
}
```

I was trying to override the paintComponent method of JPanel to paint the image, but this causes a problem in my constructor when I try to write :

```
imagepanel.paintComponents(null);
```

As it will only allow me to pass the method null, and not Graphics g, anybody know of a fix to this method or another method i can use to draw the image in the JPanel? Help is appreciated! :)

All the best and thanks in advance!
Matt

Comment: Whats the idea calling paintComponents from your constructor?. Simply remove it.

Comment: BTW - why exactly are you not painting the left-most 50 pixels of the image?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd like to suggest a more simple way,

```
  image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
  JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Yayy! Now your image is a swing component ! add it to a frame or panel or anything like you usually do! Probably need a repainting too , like

```
  jpanel.add(picLabel);
  jpanel.repaint();
```

Comment: One small note.  Given this sounds very much like an application-resource, it would normally be accessed by URL rather than File.

Comment: what if i want to draw a picture on particular x and y position

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`JLabel.setIcon()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) to place an image on the JPanel as shown [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JLabelsetIconIconicon.htm).

On the other hand, if you want to have a panel with a background, you can take a look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm) tutorial.

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Pardon Me, but isn't J2SE now known as Java SE. Regards

Comment: @GagandeepBali  What, this minute?  Sun used to change names of things so regularly that I got sick of keeping up with the latest buzz-phrases. :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Hehe, too true, just someone edited my answer once regarding this, that's why I remember it till now, else no doubt such things are hard to remember.  Regards

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to manually invoke `paintComponent()` from a constructor. The problem is that you passing null for a `Graphics` object. Instead, override `paintComponent()` and you use the `Graphics` object passed in to the method you will be using for painting. Check this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html). Here is an example of `JPanel` with image:

```
class MyImagePanel extends JPanel{ 
    BufferedImage image;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(image != null){
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```