# Add graphic using a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, icons, graphic

Is it correct to use JLabel always when you need to insert graphic or is other way? Im using Swing.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("icon.png");
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
panel.add(label);
```

Comment: You can create a custom component. For an example [see the answer by @Aqua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083096/drawing-an-image-to-a-jpanel-within-a-jframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

There's always more than one way to insert a graphic. It also depends on how you want to use the graphic. If its just for an Icon that is simplest and fastest way.

Comment: When I used this method I had some problem. What are the other methods to add graphic? I just have to create background and over it add some icons.

Comment: @user3636661 Hint, JLabel is a container, you can add other components to it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `JLabel` is the simplest method of showing an image, especially when you don't need to add any kind of effects, rotate or scale the image dynamically

You can paint the image yourself using the [2D Graphics API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). This is some what more complex and I would consider what it is your want to achieve first and weigh it up with the complexity involved.