# Change size of JFrame according to user selected image

Tags: java, jframe

I'm about to write a program using Java and i want it to have the next behavior:

- Start with a small screen, just one button (i'm going for the JMenuBar) for the user to select a image file (a country or state map)
- Once selected the image file, i'll need to resize the frame to the size of the selected image, and put the image as background.
- when the user clicks somewhere inside the frame (click on a state or city) the program will have to create a visual object there, a circle, square or any form in that coordinates.
- will need also a listener in those objects to know when they are clicked.

Summary: User has to select an image and trace a **graph** on it.

I am not asking for the code to do this. I would like to have some ideas about which components use to achieve this since i have been reading and there are plenty of ways to set the background image and stuff. But, considering the requirements, can you recommend me which components to use? I am a bit short of time since i've been given only about a week to code this, otherwise i would try all the alternatives by myself.

Some answer like:
"use a label to set the background and then resize the frame by this way: (some stuff) and then you can create a class extending from JLabel to create the circles with the listeners...." that would be enough help

I hope I was clear, any idea is welcome

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to stick with Swing I would use a [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) to select the image. Once you got the image you can easily resize the JFrame by using the `frame.setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());`

To listen for mouse clicks inside your JFrame you need to use a [MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html), make sure to add it to the frame, I always forget doing that.

Not sure whether you've succeeded drawing images/shapes at all. If not, you need to use a [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083096/drawing-an-image-to-a-jpanel-within-a-jframe) if you need extra help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a "JFrame " then you should definitely use Swing JFrames JPanels, and JLabels (as well as any other JComponents you need.) to accomplish this. Use only one JFrame. Use JPanel as the content pane/background for your JFrame and add everything else to it. But I would also suggest learning and using JavaFX because its the newest and I think it would be the easiest to use to do something like this. But if you only have a week and you know some swing use what you know. If you need more information post some code. Or ask a more direct question.